# Preventing XSS in Input $_POST Form

Tags: php

I tried to prevent XSS attacks by adding

```
// prevent XSS
$_GET   = filter_input_array(INPUT_GET, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$_POST  = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

to the top of the .PHP File. It works, but I don't think that this is the best practice.

What I need to do is improve the way this code handles the data:

```
    if (empty($_POST['telefonnummer']) || !isset($_POST['telefonnummer'])) {
        $this->setStatusMessage($translator->translate('Bitte geben Sie Ihre Telefonnummer ein.'));
        $this->setStatus(KDatabase::STATUS_FAILED);

        return false;
    }else{
      $this->telefonnummer = $_POST['telefonnummer'];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Find purpose-built libraries which are actively maintained. For example, anti-xss:

```
$harm_string = "Hello, i try to <script>alert('Hack');</script> your site";
$harmless_string = $antiXss->xss_clean($harm_string);

$harm_string = "<IMG SRC=&#x6A&#x61&#x76&#x61&#x73&#x63&#x72&#x69&#x70&#x74&#x3A&#x61&#x6C&#x65&#x72&#x74&#x28&#x27&#x58&#x53&#x53&#x27&#x29>";
$harmless_string = $antiXss->xss_clean($harm_string);

$harm_string = "<a href='&#x2000;javascript:alert(1)'>CLICK</a>";
$harmless_string = $antiXss->xss_clean($harm_string);

$harm_string = "<a href=\"\u0001java\u0003script:alert(1)\">CLICK<a>";
$harmless_string = $antiXss->xss_clean($harm_string);

$harm_string = '<li style="list-style-image: url(javascript:alert(0))">';
$harmless_string = $antiXss->xss_clean($harm_string);

$harm_string = '<li style="list-style-image: url(javascript:alert(0))">';
$antiXss->removeEvilAttributes(array('style')); // allow style-attributes
$harmless_string = $antiXss->xss_clean($harm_string);

$harm_string = "\x3cscript src=http://www.example.com/malicious-code.js\x3e\x3c/script\x3e";
$harmless_string = $antiXss->xss_clean($harm_string);

$harm_string = "<iframe width="560" onclick="alert('xss')" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/foobar?rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>";

$antiXss->removeEvilHtmlTags(array('iframe'));
```

And a UTF8 library for data you are sending:

```
UTF8::json_enocde(array(1, '¥', 'ä')); // '[1,"\u00a5","\u00e4"]'

UTF8::html_encode('中文空白'); // '&#20013;&#25991;&#31354;&#30333;'

UTF8::utf8_decode(UTF8::utf8_encode('-ABC-中文空白-')); // '-ABC-中文空白-'
```

Implement Content Security Policy(CSP) on the web server as well. For example:

```
default-src 'self' https:; connect-src 'self' https: http:; font-src 'self' https:; frame-src *; img-src
 'self' https: http: data:; media-src 'self' https:; object-src 'self' https:; script-src 'sha256-q590j1fW
+aERb666H10h55ePy0sxRjUYCiOmJPftXDs=' 'self' https: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' http:; style-src 'self'
 https: 'unsafe-inline' http:; report-uri /tracking/csp?action=listing_frame&controller=embed&req_uuid
=cff37d5d-4c12-4c8b-b288-1ce0d103a25c&version=c7fc601874a5350c79eceb33ba6d4c09a433035f;
```

> `default-src` is set to 'self' which means it's setting all CSP rules to only allow src attribute from a same-origin. In short, you should only be able to load src from a relative endpoint.
>   `frame-src` is set to wildcard (*) so we can load external src links in frames (iframe, frame, frameset). Because we're injecting HTML past the body element, we cannot use frame or frameset. The WAF has made it next to impossible to use iframe.
>   `script-src` has 'self' supplied after the sha256 hashed script for `unsafe-inline` and `unsafe-eval`, but https does not have 'self' supplied meaning we can load external scripts for execution.

**References**

- [anti-xss repo: public function testXssClean()](https://github.com/voku/anti-xss/blob/master/tests/XssTest.php#L189)
- [PayloadsAllTheThings/XSS injection at master · swisskyrepo/PayloadsAllTheThings](https://github.com/swisskyrepo/PayloadsAllTheThings/tree/master/XSS%20injection)
- [UTF8 can be tricky – especially with PHP – DerEuroMark](https://www.dereuromark.de/2014/08/15/utf8-can-be-tricky-especially-with-php/)
- [voku/portable-utf8:  Portable UTF-8 library - performance optimized (unicode) string functions for php.](https://github.com/voku/portable-utf8#utf8_encodestring-str--string)
- [Airbnb – When Bypassing JSON Encoding, XSS Filter, WAF, CSP, and Auditor turns into Eight Vulnerabilities | Brett Buerhaus](https://buer.haus/2017/03/08/airbnb-when-bypassing-json-encoding-xss-filter-waf-csp-and-auditor-turns-into-eight-vulnerabilities/)
- [How to protect PHP application from XSS attacks: CSP 3 nonce | PHP & Symfony Tips](https://ikvasnica.com/blog/how-to-protect-php-application-from-xss-attacks-csp-3-nonce/)

Answer (score 0):

It is not your input which is prone to XSS but only output.

So you should leave input alone and sanitize the output. For the purpose I would recommend a template engine with auto-escaping feature, for example Twig.